# how do I set up svn in work project

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am still new in this svn (tortoise) and I'm still learning on how to use this. I created my repository in the root of drive c:. and my web project located at this path c:\wamp\www\my_webapp. should I put the 3 folders (branches,tags,trunk) and inside the trunk I have folder "inventory" and I will put all my php files js etc...? or should I creat another folder in other location like c:\  and put inside those 3 folders.then I will just copy the modified files into trunk then make `svncommit`.

This is the scenario that I am having.

**First** I create repository using tortoise in c:\myrepo, then I generate also the 3 folders(branches,trunks,tags).

**Second** I create new folder "mywebsitesvn" in c:\mywebsitesvn. after that I import my mywebsite folder which located in c:\wamp\www\mywebsite to c:\mywebsitesv now I make some first commit by adding mywebsite in mywebsitesvn.

Now when I made some changes in my code or update some js files from this location c:\wamp\www\mywebsite example I am updating my index.html,after I update the index.html I copied it to my mywebsitesvn then make some commit.

My question for this.Is this the correct way ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should follow the tutorial in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). You don't *copy modified files* at all. The book explains how version control works, and does so with pretty good examples. Or you could use the TortoiseSVN help file and go through the *Getting Started* section, especially the *Basic Concepts* topic..

Comment: @KenWhite so I will create folder structure like this c:\wamp\www\workprojects\trunk\mywebsite . so inside the trunk is my website folder and in the website folder are my php files etc..?

Comment: @KenWhite am I right because you said that I will not need anymore to create another folder where I can place my updated file.

Comment: I've referred you to two separate tutorials for using SVN. It doesn't make sense for me to write another one here as well. :-) Go through the TortoiseSVN help file section I mentioned, which explains exactly how to configure your source for version control and how to use it afterward.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you I got it now and it works :)